# How to display form data in antd table without creating a new table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Am using reactjs to display my form data in antd table. But when I fill-in and submit another data, it creates another table to display the data which is not suppose to be.
Am not sure the code to make it display all the data from the form in one table. Here is my screenshot of what am explaining - [image]
Heres's my code to display the form data in antd table:

```js
import {Table} from 'antd';

const Customer = ({
  id,
  title,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  address,
  phone,
  date,
  handleRemoveCustomer,
}) => {

  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([
    {
      id: id,
      title: title,
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      address: address,
      phone: phone,
      date: date
    }
  ])

    const columns = [
      {
        key: '1',
        title: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'id'
      },

      {
        key: '2',
        title: 'Title',
        dataIndex: 'title'
      },

      {
        key: '3',
        title: 'FirstName',
        dataIndex: 'firstname'
      },

      {
        key: '4',
        title: 'LastName',
        dataIndex: 'lastname'
      },

      {
        key: '5',
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address'
      },

      {
        key: '6',
        title: 'PhoneNumber',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
      },

    ];


  return (
    <div className='customer'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <Table 
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={dataSource}
          ></Table>
      </header>
    </div>
    ....
```

Also the following is my form code:

```js
const CustomerForm = (props) => {

  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(() => {
    return {
      title: props.customer ? props.customer.title : '',
      firstname: props.customer ? props.customer.firstname : '',
      lastname: props.customer ? props.customer.lastname : '',
      address: props.customer ? props.customer.address : '',
      phone: props.customer ? props.customer.phone : '',
      date: props.customer ? props.customer.date : ''
    };
  });

  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
  const {title, firstname, lastname, address, phone } = customer;

  const handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const values = [title, firstname, lastname, address, phone];
    let errorMsg = '';

    const allFieldsFilled = values.every((field) => {
      const value = `${field}`.trim();
      return value !== '' && value !== '0';
    });

    if (allFieldsFilled) {
      const customer = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        address,
        phone,
        date: new Date()
      };
      props.handleOnSubmit(customer);
    } else {
      errorMsg = 'Please fill out all the fields.';
    }
    setErrorMsg(errorMsg);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    switch (name) {
      case 'phone':
        if (value === '' || parseInt(value) === +value) {
          setCustomer((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value
          }));
        }
        break;
      case 'amount':
        if (value === '' || value.match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{0,2})?$/)) {
          setCustomer((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value
          }));
        }
        break;
      default:
        setCustomer((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          [name]: value
        }));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-form">
      {errorMsg && <p className="errorMsg">{errorMsg}</p>}
      <Form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
      <Form.Group controlId="title">
          <Form.Label> Title</Form.Label>
          <select name='title' value={title} onChange={handleInputChange}>
            <option value="select">Select title</option>
            <option value="mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
            <option value="miss">Miss</option>
          </select>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="name">
          <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            className="input-control"
            type="text"
            name="firstname"
            value={firstname}
            placeholder="Enter first name"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="name">
          <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            className="input-control"
            type="text"
            name="lastname"
            value={lastname}
            placeholder="Enter last name"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="address">
          <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            className="input-control"
            type="text"
            name="address"
            value={address}
            placeholder="Enter address"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="phone">
          <Form.Label>Phone Number</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            className="input-control"
            type="number"
            name="phone"
            value={phone}
            placeholder="Enter phone number"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="submit-btn">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you include your form code in the question

Comment: Ok, I will just a minute

Comment: I believe where am missing it is this code here: const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([
    {
      id: id,
      title: title,
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      address: address,
      phone: phone,
      date: date
    }
  ])

Comment: since you are calling `props.handleOnSubmit(customer)`, maybe you are mapping over `customers` in the parent component and creating one `Customer` element for every `customer` object. right?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: it's exactly the reason you see multiple table on the screen, if you want to see just one table on the screen you should send all customers to `Customer` component, also you don't need `dataSource` state in the Customer component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240795/discussion-between-benjamin-ikwuagwu-and-saeed-shamloo).

Comment: where is code for parent component which is using/rendering Customer component